# Flex wrap does not working in td tag in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

This markup works in Chrome as expected. Can I make it work in IE11 using css?

```
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around;flex-wrap: wrap;">
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which version of IE? https://caniuse.com/?search=flex-wrap

Comment: Added in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 wants to have explicit value of `width` sometimes.  So we can use `display: grid` instead.

An example:

```css
td > div >{   
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns: 100px minmax(200px, 500px) 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 100px minmax(200px, 500px) 1fr;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td >
              <div>
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
                <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls width=250 height=150></video>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working, I quess it`s because of td tag.

Comment: @DenisMalakhov try to add to `td` tag like that `<td style="width: 100%">`

Comment: @DenisMalakhov or `<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-around;flex-wrap: wrap;align-items: stretch;">`

Comment: not working. I guess IE can not process flex-wrap inside td. Looks like a bug.

Comment: @DenisMalakhov if it is eligible, then try to use `dispaly: grid`. Please, see my updated answer. It works